# Need help running total for row and coulmn

Tags: javascript

Actually i need running total for row and column in same page. I am tried to use nth child function. The below code is working for row running total and now i need to add column total function. can some one help me with this.

```
<script>
$ (document).ready(function() {

    $ ("tbody:nth-child(2) tr").each(function(){

      var col1 = $ (this).find("td:nth-child(2) span span:nth-child(2)").find("input[type='text']");
      var col2 = $ (this).find("td:nth-child(3) span span:nth-child(2)").find("input[type='text']");
      var col3 = $ (this).find("td:nth-child(4) span span:nth-child(2)").find("input[type='text']");

      setInterval(function(){
         var num1 = 0;
         var num2 = 0;
         num1 = parseInt(col1.val(),10);
         num2 = parseInt(col2.val(),10);
         sum = num1 + num2;
         if( !isNaN(sum) )
         col3.val(parseInt((num1 + num2),10));     
      },1)

    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Edit your question and add your HTML to this as well

Comment: There's no need to run that code 1000 times per second. You should rather run it as needed by adding a `oninput` event listener to all your `<input>`s. (Also, `tbody tr` should suffice, since a table shouldn't have multiple bodies)

Comment: could you help me how to dynamic column total using nth child or else any simple method?